# I would like to backup the content of a remote computer using MobaXterm

Tags: ssh, backup, mobaxterm

I am using MobaXterm to ssh into a computer cluster and it is working super smoothly. However, I would like to backup all the files I have on the remote computer to my personal device once in a while. I would like to do so without having to download all the files every time. In other words, I am looking for a tool to make a backup of the incremental changes in my files.
Is there such a tool?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure MobaXterm includes `rsync`, which is just what you need.  `rsync` can copy (pull or push) all changed files from one computer to another, and it works over `ssh` just fine.

Not knowing your exact machines or directories, here's a sample that will get you started in the right direction:

```
rsync -avz --delete user@remote:/path/to/directory/to/backup/ local-backup-dir/
```

NOTE: the trailing slash `/` on each of those directories is **IMPORTANT**, and I suggest you read the man page for `rsync` carefully.

Another useful thing: `-n` (or `--dry-run`) - add that argument to `rsync` to see what it would do **before** you remove it and run it "for real"